# Is this login form with possible with WebAuthn?

Tags: biometrics, webauthn

[image][image: Website prototype login form]

I'm trying to plan a rewrite of my website and I want to make it that I can login passwordless with just Windows Hello, TouchID, or FaceID using WebAuthn. All the examples online have a whole popup situation but I want it done like my mockup. I also want my website to detect the default biometric and have the biometric icon change to the icon representing the default one, for example, face icon for FaceID. This website will be done using python-flask, ReactJS, MySQL, CSS, and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different points to hit on here -

**Pop-up/Modal**

We'll start with this one. Unfortunately the pop-ups that appear during the WebAuthn ceremony are part of the browsers implementation. Every time the get()/create() methods are called the pop-ups will be invoked. There is some work coming out from Google/Apple in their passkey implementation where this will look more like an ["autofill" experience](https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/wiki/Explainer:-WebAuthn-Conditional-UI), but you will still be required to use their pop-ups.

**Defaulting to Windows Hello, Touch ID, etc..**

I'll start by suggesting that you shouldn't constrain your users to only the [platform authenticators](https://developers.yubico.com/WebAuthn/WebAuthn_Developer_Guide/Platform_vs_Cross-Platform.html). Security keys still play a big role in WebAuthn and work really well for signing in across devices. Relying on platform authenticators could limit your users to the device they initially registered with, or limit users who don't have a biometric sensor on their device.

With that being said, you can explicitly invoke the use of only platform authenticators using the [PublicKeyCreationOptions](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dictdef-publickeycredentialcreationoptions). In the property [authenticatorSelection](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dictdef-authenticatorselectioncriteria) there is a field [authenticatorAttachment](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dom-authenticatorselectioncriteria-authenticatorattachment). If you set this field to "platform" then your platform authenticator will be invoked (if one is available).

Here's an example of the request sent by the relying party (note the property authenticatorSelection towards the bottom):

```
{
  "publicKey": {
    "rp": {
    "name": "Example Inc",
    "id": "example.com/"
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "user",
    "displayName": "user",
    "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "challenge": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "pubKeyCredParams": [***],
  "excludeCredentials": [***],
  "authenticatorSelection": {
    "authenticatorAttachment": "platform"
    "residentKey": "preferred",
    "userVerification": "preferred"
  },
  "attestation": "direct",
  "extensions": {}
  }
}
```

**Detecting default biometric**

I have a React example [here](https://github.com/YubicoLabs/WebAuthnKit/blob/main/clients/web/react/src/_helpers/DetectBrowser.ts). Some things to note on this approach:

- There are more elegant and accurate ways of determining what platform the user is on. This snippet will work a majority of the time, but there is a lot of assumption happening based only on the detected OS
- There's no icons included, I would suggest adding an imgSrc field to the enums that includes a link to the source image

Hope this helps.